# Multi files upload form problem

Tags: webforms, multifile-uploader

I'm creating a form that allows users to upload 11 images, i have 11 input fields for the user can select an image for each. The problem is that i can only upload the images from the first 5 input fields, the rest i cant.

What can be the problem? There are some limitation of the number of Input fields for each form? Any idea?

Thanks
Bruno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the post on submit is too big, try smaller images see if you can upload more than 5

Comment: Hi, Already tried that. Even with only one image but added in one of the input fields after the field number 5 and doesnt work.

Comment: Hmm, that's tough, did you make sure the fields all have the same naming convention, input1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,... I'm guessing your looping through them by name.

Comment: Already checked that also. Tried to remove the first 2 fields and then i can upload with the next 2 also. So its not the problem of the naming. I think it may be some kind of restriction, just dont know where.

Comment: What kind of web server are you running?

Comment: Tell people what container and framework your running on, somebody might now if there are restrictions.

Comment: Have a look to the server details and definitions: [link](http://development.propertyforsaleinportugal.com/test.php)

Comment: Hi Glenn, Sorry! I deleted the file. Already managed to solved the problem. I used another upload class and worked just fine. thanks